# <Query syntax failing

Tags: react-apollo, next.js, strapi

All right. Need some fresh eyes to spot my error:

Trying to grab content for a JS Carousel from a mongo db via GraphQL (as produced by strapi).

Working in a component with relevant imports:

```
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Carousel, CarouselItem, CarouselControl, CarouselIndicators, CarouselCaption } from 'reactstrap'
```

within my class

```
...snippet...
render() {
  const GET_CAROUSELS = gql`
     query carousels {
        carousels {
          _id
          caption_header
          caption_text
          alt_text
          slide_file { url }
        }
     }`
return (
   <Query query={GET_CAROUSELS} errorPolicy="all">
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        let cars = data.carousels
        if (error) console.log(error)
        if (!cars || cars.length == 0){
          return <div>No Carousels found</div>
        } else {
          return (
             <React.Fragment>
              <Carousel activeIndex={this.activeIndex}
                        next={this.next}
                        previous={this.previous} >
                {cars.map(carousel => (
                   <CarouselItem key={carousel._id}>
                      <img scr={carousel.slide_file.url} />
                  </CarouselItem>
                ))}
             </Carousel>
```

I've tried many permutations, and this current code errors with `cannot read property of 'map' undefined`

My QLGraph playground shows that this query works fine:

```
 query {carousels {
    _id
   caption_header
   caption_text
   alt_text
   slide_file { url }
  }
 }
```

I've tried altering the `<Query query`, to no avail. Tried with and without letting `let cars = data.carousels` sometimes just `let cars=carousels`, etc. 
Help, my eyes hurt.

Comment: I take for granted that there are no errors logged (from Query console.log). Have you tried logging or debugging the data object? What is it returned with the data object? I cant reproduce the error I would need to know your graphql endpoint and then setup a client and so on.

Comment: let cars = data.carousels; can you console.log(cars) and show me your result may be we can help.